# Validating the identity of the caller between multiple services with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I have a client, which calls a service (passing it a user id and password).  The first service can validate these credentials against users in a database.  The first service then needs to call another service, but this second service cannot be passed the user id and password given to the first service (this is a requirement outside of my control).

[image]

The services will most likely be on different domains and both exposed to the internet (so security is a big issue here).

I am therefore looking at options for how the second service should check/validate that it is being called by my first service (and not by someone else trying to impersonate it).

One idea I've had is to add an additional service that acts as an authentication service, this could issue a token that is then passed to the second service which in turn calls the authentication service to check the token.  Another idea (from a colleague) has been to assign an SSL certificate to each service, and check the certificate when the call comes into Server B - I haven't seen certificates used in this way though so am not sure if it's viable.

This is still at the design stage, so I am open to alternative ideas/approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easy fix, then creating an extra set of credentials for service A so that service B can be sure it's called from an authorized party without knowing the clients credentials might be enough.

In the long run, something like [Windows Identity Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Identity_Foundation) sounds exactly like your plans with the authentication service.

Answer (score 0):

So, both A and B parties are exposed to the internet (distrusted environment). Taking into account security requirements what you need is *mutual WCF authentication*. Certificates are the easiest way to achieve the goal - your server has to ensure that proper client calls it and the client has to be sure it calls proper server (DNS attacks, etc.). That means each party must have public key of the other to authenticate. Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348595/Use-Mutual-SSL-Authentication-in-WCF) for the details on how to configure your server and client.